# Cookie + db token + session authentication, can i do away with the sessions

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, cookies

I have a little web app, which uses a lot of ajax. After someone logs in, what we need to keep persistent is their user_id and group_id

The way I first did authentication, I just stored these as clear txt in cookies ( $_COOKIE['user_id'], $_COOKIE['group_id'] ). Obviously that was bad since you could modify both values!

I'm not an experienced programmer and don't need massively amazing security for this app. But that was pretty bad.

So, I moved on to creating a token in the database, which stores the user_id, group_id and a hash token and then putting that token only in the cookie. The user_id and group_id are created as sessions once the token is authenticated (cookie match database).

This is more secure but the whole thing of having to manage the user_id and group_id sessions (timeouts, reinitialising) vs just grabbing them from cookies has caused a lot of grief and made my app's actual functioning less reliable.

Now accepting my level of skill, and that the easy management + robust functioning of my app is more important than high level security... I'm wondering if I could do away with the sessions, and do a compromise by still storing the user_id and group id in a cookie but along with the hash - i.e.

COOKIE['token'] = user_id_val+group_id_val+hash_in_db

would look like: 23-144-jhwr8324398fjk2j49083223n23

So all I need is a little function to parse that string and do everything from that. Someone could change the values but obviously the hash won't match.

Is this ok?

Comment: As an alternative, read the cookie value at the top of each script and pull the user id and group id in fresh each time. That way, your session won't time out as long as the cookie exists.

Comment: You still need to maintain a list of valid tokens, otherwise someone could just start putting different ids in there and much you all up: `22_345_fasfsdfdfklsdflk`...  Sure, the hash may not match, but with rainbow tables and brute force, it wouldn't be too hard to figure out any static salt that you're using.  Remind me again what the problem with just using a regular session is (PHP based sessions)?

Comment: For this app, 'remember me' behaviour is the default, because it's often kept open in the background. So a cookie is necessary. So for simplicity, if I can do it all from the cookie, the better. Also, at the moment, I am trying to authenticate on the cookie and recreate the sessions if required at the top of each script but it just seems a bit flakey. Sorry I can't be more exact. I realised that proper session management would be fine but it seems easier to me do stick with the cookie only route, as long as it's not too insecure.

Comment: So why do you think storing the user ID and group ID along with the hash is a better solution than storing just the hash? Do you hope to skip the hash lookup and use the user ID and group ID without verifying the data?

Comment: And yeah, I would still be generating and storing the matching tokens in MySQL, no problem there. I would just recreate them when they logout/login. But because of the way this app works, most people stay logged in for a long period of time

Comment: I haven't thought this through enough. As you guys have pointed out, I could just store the cookie hash and then look that up alone to get the user_id and group id. The downside of this vs sessions is perfomance, having to do that extra query every time an ajax call is made. And since I have some auto-refreshes going on every 30sec, this is a big deal I suppose

Comment: @orchid: It shouldn't be a big deal as long as you set the hash to be a UNIQUE key in MySQL...  That way it's a simple efficient lookup and will most likely be cached by MySQL...  It's not a big deal at all as most sites do it this way.  An alternative would be to store it in something like memcached or apc...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need cookies at all (well, except for the session cookie) for authentication. Here's an example of a simple cookie-less authentication:

```
session_start();

// $db is a pseudo object for database access

// Verify login
$auth = false;
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && isset($_SESSION['user_hash'])) {
   $user = $db->getUserById($_SESSION['user_id']);
   if ($user) {
      $hash = sha1($user->id.$user->salt);
      if ($hash === $_SESSION['user_hash']) $auth = true;
   }
}

// Make login
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
   $user = $db->getUserByCredentials($_POST['login'], $_POST['password']);
   if ($user) {
      $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->id;
      $_SESSION['user_hash'] = sha1($user->id.$user->salt);
      // redirect...
   }
   // redirect to error page
}
```

Of course, this can be improved to add defence mechanisms against all sorts of attacks, store user information, etc. but this is the basic idea. It's way more secure than using cookies.